# Handling Missing Values

Tags: missing-data, data-preprocessing

I have the following artificial data :

[image]

Now I am trying to handle missing values in the age and salary columns using mean imputation. I am using the following code to do so :

```
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
imputer= SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan , strategy="mean")
x_train[:, 1:3]=imputer.fit_transform(x_train[:,1:3])
```

The output is :

[image]

I have calculated these mean values manually but the results didnt agree with each other ! For example for the age imputation, I have added the non-empty cells in that column divided by 9 ( excluding the empty cell) :

```
mean of column = (44+27+30+38+40+35+48+50+37)/9 = 38.77
```

The result is 38.77, however, the result was 38.43 by imputer object. Same for the purchased column as the results didn’t agree with each other. What is wrong with my understanding ?